# How to defragment files in size less than 100MB only in ext4 filesystem

Tags: ext4, defragmentation

I have a very basic idea:

I would like to defragment files in size less than 100MB only in ext4 filesystem.

Since there is no option for that in the defragmentation tool (`e4defrag`), any ideas how I could achieve that?

I know only how to find those files:

```
find / -type f -size -100M
```

Reason for such action:

I had a system with 99.x% of the fs occupied, I freed the space now, leaving many files fragmented.

Comment: First check to see if de-fragmentation needs doing. `ext` file systems don't get as fragmented as `fat` or `ntfs`. About the only scenario that causes excessive fragmentation slowly appending to a file (and even this is reduced by `ext`. So if your partition is mostly log files, then it may fragment. To mitigate this, as part of log rotation, zip the older logs. This will, as well as saving space, de-frag the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was a hair away from a solution:

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -size -100M -exec e4defrag {} +
```

---

Notes:

- the `-xdev` argument as man page says:

  > Don't descend directories on other filesystems.

  This means it will not process any other filesystems like `tmpfs` (`/tmp`) etc., see `mount -v` for all you have mounted.